# Download and view a prototype on iPad without internet

Tags: html, ios, server, zurb-foundation, local

Does anybody know of a way to download a prototype (in this case Zurb Foundation) and run it on an iPad without an internet connection?

This is needed for a demonstration where we cannot rely on there being WiFi or cellular available. On a computer this is easy, with the use of something like Fenix, where you just add a local folder which contains your html and assets, give it a port and run.

Is there anything similar for iOS?

Edit: I have found through another question that using Coda enables this. I've tried it out and it does work, but it's very fiddly. But the functionality is there, it runs a local server and you can view the files. If there was an app that "just" did this, without the whole code editor side it'd be amazing!

Could somebody explain why this question is getting downvoted?

Thanks

Comment: Host the html files on a local laptop running a web server and connect the iPad to the laptop via Wifi?

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm afraid that won't be possible as the sales people would just have an iPad with them

Comment: I think there is a webscrapping tutorial in Swift. Maybe you could use that to get the whole html file and probably just store it as a huge string that can be ran offline by injecting html into a wkwebview?

Answer (score 3):

> On a computer this is easy, with the use of something like Fenix, where you just add a local folder which contains your html and assets, give it a port and run.

Do the same on your mac and make sure it is running on your local server (just open safari and type "localhost" in the address bar and see the result".

Here is my result:
[image]

After, open network settings and create a new Network:

[image]

Give a name to your network and click the "Create" button.

[image]

Then, open the Settings app on your iPhone, disable "Cellular Data" if enabled, then go to the "Wifi" settings and connect to the newly created network. (It may take some time to appear in the list, so be patient.)

[image]

Then, open the terminal app on your mac, type **"ifconfig |grep -w inet"** and find your local IP address (it will something other than 127.0.0.1).

Now, open the Safari app on your iPhone, and type that IP address in the address bar.

[image]

You'll see the same result as your Mac's Safari without the internet connection.

Pretty simple, huh?

So just configure the site on your macbook to run it locally without internet, and take that macbook with you to the demonstration.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest, simpliest, idea (given that you want to display a 'prototype' and not a functioning site) would be to: take/save screenshots of your key pages and illustrations of the primary sales points. Assemble them in whatever order is neccessary for your presentation. Combining all of the files (example: in a PDF) will keep everything organized and allow you to email it to the sales staff prior to their meeting.

Answer (score 0):

To build the app you are suggesting, I would suggest you do the following:

1. Have a way to provision the "content" onto the device, such as via HTTP when online, and store it to file
2. Run an iOS-compatible HTTP server such as [Kitura](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura) or [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer) to serve the content
3. Utilise [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller) to view the locally hosted content

I recommend having both the server and client in the same app. Having the app just serve the content and using Safari as a client would be difficult, as the server will be suspected when you switch to Safari.

This is assuming your prototype is simple content such as html, css, files, and javascript. If more "moving parts" are required, such as a database, that will be more complex.

Comment: I don’t think you can evaluate JavaScript or HTML with SFSafariViewController or did I miss read something from the docs? I think you can only do that from wkwebview.

Comment: SFSafariViewController provides a "visible standard interface for browsing the web". I've suggested a web server be run on the iOS device to server the content locally and SFSafariViewController be used as the client.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing this approach. This might seem scrappy, but it should work and be simple ish if you do everything right.

Scrape all of the html content from the page. You can either do this from Swift or just put all the local html files.

You then could all take the Javascript code with it to to keep the interactivity offline.

Then run through a wkwebview that is empty then inject the HTML and evaluate the JavaScript. Swift has support for these without any 3rd party plugins. You could then load the css with JavaScript rather than using html since those are the only things I can think would work.

You wouldn’t need an internet connection since the stuff is injected locally. You then could add a couple of text views that can run as a simple code editor for the html and JavaScript. That’s about all I think the closet to the Fenix service for IOS.

You would also might be needing to either separate the JavaScript from the html or create your own parser for JavaScript from the huge string you are going to get from scraping the site.

You would also have to reinvent git if you want the thing to get updated from the iPhone entirely, but I think that’s all you would need to be able to run the website offline. Also don’t forget to add an array of html files and css that corresponds to it so you can have it change pages without internet connection.

(Core data is your friend here. Save the sites so you don’t have to scrape it again.)