# How to serve a web app running on a Mac on a local network, without a router?

Tags: server, network-programming, localhost

### The problem

I'm working on a little **local web app, relaying on two independant devices**, a mobile used as a remote and a laptop used as a display, connected to the same local server (running on the laptop) through a shared network. The client-side app (Vite + Vue) serves on localhost:5173 , the server-side (PHP) serves on localhost:8888.
For now, it works since both devices are connected to the same WIFI network. The desktop runs the local server that the mobile can access through its IP address (http://168.192.X.XX:5173). But **the app is supposed to be able to work in an area without internet**, neither 3G/4G/5G nor WIFI.

I wonder if it's possible to make it work without a WIFI router ? If yes, how ?

### What I tried

Following [an Apple guide](https://support.apple.com/fr-fr/guide/mac-help/mchl98b9beb6/mac), I tried to create a network on the Mac. I can connect to it from the mobile but I can't access the localhost, maybe because the network isn't secure ?

Please, tell me if my question isn't clear before disliking it.

Comment: `Download and view a prototype on iPad without internet` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52753952/download-and-view-a-prototype-on-ipad-without-internet/52918537#52918537

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I try this as soon as possible.